# Can't boot from linux USB boot disk after installing 18.04

Tags: 18.04, usb-drive

So this is friggen weird...

I installed 18.04 desktop. Played around a bit and decided I wanted to drop back to 16.04... only problem is that any USB drive I created with ubuntu on it wouldn't boot. I use the exact same USB and create it with the exact same software but with windows on it and it boots up no problem...

It's an old computer running legacy bios. Gets stuck at the verifying DMI pool data.

Any clue what's going on?

Comment: Which tool did you use to create the LiveUSB; Startup Disk Creator from within Ubuntu 18, or something else? Did you redownload the ISO for 16.04 from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads? Did you verify it by checksum  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu?_ga=2.205530267.966281298.1533248007-1423409380.1533248007#0  before creating the LiveUSB for 16?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like my hardware just isn't keen on 16.04... reinstalling 18.04 works *shrug*